# display a webpage in to 3 vertical sections with ability to move and stretch the menus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]I am creating a web page with 3 vertical templates. I used bootstrap grids and the grids are fixed but I want to strech them .Is there any way to do in Angular js and bootstrap.

Here is my code:

```
  <body ng-controller="MenuController as menuCtrl">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class=" col-lg-3 mainmenu"> 
                    <h1> main menu </h1>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 secondmenu">
                    <h1> second menu </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 thirdmenu">
                    <h1> detailed view </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

here is  my css file is:

```
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}

/* only for column content visible */
.col-lg-1>div {
    background-color:#ddd;
}
```

Comment: Try adding a screenshot to see what you have and maybe a mockup for us to better understand what you want

Comment: have you tried anything to get them to work? If so, can you post an example of what you have done?

Comment: I added jquery script to resize  <script>
  $(function() {
   $(".resizable").resizable({
    handles: 'e, w'
});
  });

Comment: but it is not functioning as I expected. how do i get 3 menus with able to move ,resize without loosing data in menus?after adding jquery script when I move second view I am losing third view , the data inside the layouts are moving. can anyone help me?